# SoftwareSerial error

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, softwareserial

I have arduino , upon arduino I have Arduino GSM shield (Tx-2, Rx-3, Modem reset-7) and upon it, I have the Adafruit GPS Logger shield. I am trying to send sms of Latitude  from the GPS Logger shield to my numer through GSM shield. I am getting a error ..

```
SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial.cpp.o: In function `SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial(unsigned char, unsigned char, bool)':
/home/thiyagu/Downloads/arduino/arduino-1.0.5/libraries/SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial.cpp:335: multiple definition of `__vector_3'

GSM/GSM3SoftSerial.cpp.o:/home/thiyagu/Downloads/arduino/arduino-1.0.5/libraries/GSM/GSM3SoftSerial.cpp:148: first defined here
SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial.cpp.o: In function `SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial(unsigned char, unsigned char, bool)':
/home/thiyagu/Downloads/arduino/arduino-1.0.5/libraries/SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial.cpp:335: multiple definition of `__vector_4'

GSM/GSM3SoftSerial.cpp.o:/home/thiyagu/Downloads/arduino/arduino-1.0.5/libraries/GSM/GSM3SoftSerial.cpp:148: first defined here
SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial.cpp.o: In function `SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial(unsigned char, unsigned char, bool)':
/home/thiyagu/Downloads/arduino/arduino-1.0.5/libraries/SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial.cpp:335: multiple definition of `__vector_5'

GSM/GSM3SoftSerial.cpp.o:/home/thiyagu/Downloads/arduino/arduino-1.0.5/libraries/GSM/GSM3SoftSerial.cpp:148: first defined here
```

What is the meaning of this error ? what should I do to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

This error means, that there is library overlapping on a vectors. To solve this error, you need to modify your Library file :

STEPS :

1. Remove the Softserial Library
2. Download AltSoftSerial library
3. if you have shield then you need to replace AltSoftSerial in place of SoftwareSerial in both .cpp as well as .h files.
4. Import AltSoftSerial library in place of SoftwareSerial in the sketch.

Execute .